# Disabling digraphs in vim

Tags: vim, digraphs

I have an unusual problem with my gVim installation - approximately half the time that I turn on my computer, gVim automatically replaces character sequences such as 'a and "o with their corresponding digraph characters. The other half of the time, it doesn't. I do not want this feature as it makes typing strings and other sequences very frustrating. But I can find no way to disable it.

This does not appear to be the default digraph options, since those use either backspace or CTRL-K to do anything. What could this be? The only package I have in my vimfiles folder is pyflakes. I have tried setting the keymap to the default and checking that I don't have the EasyAccents plugin installed somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Try `gvim -u NONE`. It will skip vimrc and plugins.

Comment: That stops it from happening! Obviously I'd rather not use this permanently since my plugins and vimrc are rather helpful. Is my vimrc suspect then? Edit: actually, just reruning gvim fixes it (temporarily at least), so this doesn't tell me much.

Comment: Try `gvim -u NORC`. It will only skip vimrc.

Comment: Try `gvim --noplugin`. It will only skip plugins.

Comment: Since it's now working with just plain `gvim`, that it works with both of those commands doesn't mean much. I think I'm getting hit by the problem where this only happens some of the time and I might have to perform lots of rebooting to thoroughly test this. Regardless, thanks, these commands are good to know.

Comment: I just came back from having my computer in sleep mode and now my open gVim has reverted to the bad behavior. Before sleeping, it was not having this problem. New gvims do not have this problem, still.

Comment: Well, I just observed this behavior in Chrome for the first time outside of vim. So I'm calling this closed and that vim is not the problem. (Though I have installed Vrome which provides vim-like behavior for Chrome, I doubt a vim problem would emerge in Vrome.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check, that no keymap is defined. Check the output of `:verbose set keymap?` 
It sounds to me, like some plugin is setting the accents keymap and therefore replacing e.g.
'a by á

Otherwise if that doesn't help, use paste mode, which basically disables all postprocessing
by Vim when entering characters. The `pastetoggle` setting is useful for this.

In any case, check the [faq Question 36.12](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-36.12) for how to debug problems with your .vimrc or plugins.

Comment: Output of `:verbose set keymap?` is `keymap=`. Even with paste enabled I have the same problem.

Comment: Interestingly. In paste mode, this shouldn't really happen. Do you have some kind of Input Method Editor set up? Possibly setting `imdisable` works then.

Comment: Trying `imdisable` gives an error that it is not an editor command.

Comment: Ah, that executes, but doesn't change any behavior.